# How to flush memory during low memory warning level 1 or 2 or 3 in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, memory-management

My app consumes memory around 70 Mb. So i need to flush it out when i've low memory warning level 1 or 2.

Comment: To have join our hands you have to show us your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller this function will invokes once you have low memory warning:

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Release any unused objects, nil any unused properties while running a class. release + nil all outlets in dealloc, nil all outlets in viewDidUnload. Also release all objects that you have "alloc"-ated, "retain"-ed or "copied". Use Profiler to detect memory leaks. Post you code if you want concrete answer. Your question is a matter of wrong memory management, and this is a huge area that depends on many things.